# String Replacement and Matching in Python 2

Tags: python

I have user posts that I would like to match up with a predetermined list of patterns(see example). If the post matches a pattern, I would like to write the post and the pattern to a file. What is the best way to do this? So far I've only thought of brute forcing it with 4 for loops and then doing some comparisons. I already have the lists of all the data I need, below are just some very simple examples to give you an idea of what I am looking for.

---

**Example**

**Posts:**

```
posts =['When I ate at McDonald\'s, I felt sick.',
'I like eating at Burger King.',
'Wendy\'s made me feel happy.']
```

**Pattern:**

```
patterns = ['When I ate at [RESTAURANT]',
'I like eating at [RESTAURANT]',
'[RESTAURANT] made me feel [FEELING]',
'I felt [FEELING]']
```

**Lists:**

```
restaurant_names = ['McDonald\'s', 'Burger King', 'Wendy\'s']

feelings = ['happy', 'sick', 'tired']
```

**OutputFile:**

When I ate at `[RESTAURANT]`, When I ate at McDonald's, I felt sick.

I felt `[FEELING]`, When I ate at McDonald's, I felt sick.

`[RESTAURANT]` made me feel `[FEELING]`, Wendy's made me feel happy.

I like eating at `[RESTAURANT]`, I like eating at Burger King.

---

-Sorry for the formatting, but this is my first post on stackoverflow after lurking for a while. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: check out [`nltk`](http://nltk.org/).

Comment: Is there something specific to look for in nltk? I'll go take a look right nowbut was wondering if you had recommendation for a starting point. Thanks!

Comment: NLTK is the Natural Language Toolkit.  The patterns that you are searching for might be more robust if you were to use it to parse the language instead of searching for specific sequences of characters.

Comment: By the way, your code samples are not valid Python.

Comment: What output format do you want?

Comment: I was planning on just outputting in a csv format.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
>>> sentences = ["When I ate at McDonald's, I felt sick.", 'I like eating at Burger King.', 
    "Wendy's made me feel happy."]
>>> patterns = {"McDonald's": "[RESTAURANT]", "Burger King": "[RESTAURANT]", 
    "Wendy's": "[RESTAURANT]", "happy": "[FEELING]", "sick": "[FEELING]", 
    "tired": "[FEELING]"}
```

Then you can do

```
>>> for sentence in sentences:
...     replaced = sentence
...     for pattern in patterns:
...         if pattern in sentence:
...             replaced = replaced.replace(pattern, patterns[pattern])
...     print sentence
...     print replaced
...
When I ate at McDonald's, I felt sick.
When I ate at [RESTAURANT], I felt [FEELING].
I like eating at Burger King.
I like eating at [RESTAURANT].
Wendy's made me feel happy.
[RESTAURANT] made me feel [FEELING].
```

This still needs some work (for example, right now, the word `carsick` would become `car[FEELING]`), and you might want to avoid all the repetition in the `patterns` values by creating another list of replacement texts that you can refer to by index, but perhaps this is enough to get you started?

Comment: Would this work if I had a list of about 20,000 [RESTAURANT] and let's just say the same number of [FEELING] entries?

Comment: It would work with the same limitations I mentioned above, but it would be quite wasteful and not very efficient. Perhaps you want to clarify your actual problem/situation in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand.  Could you please post the exact code you have so far, what you intend to do and why?  Thanks.

In general, there are 4 alternatives:

1)  Use a single, but complex, RegEx pattern and strict lists

```
r"(When I ate at (?P<rest1>McDonald's|Burger King|Wendy's), I felt (?P<feel1>happy|sick|tired)\.)|(I like eating at (?P<rest2>McDonald's|Burger King|Wendy's)\.)"
```

Analysis of the named capture groups `rest1`, `feel1`, `rest2` would allow you to determine what sentence type was used if you need it.  Otherwise, you can output the whole match.   The pattern can, of course, be assembled programatically from your lists.  Just be careful of using `re.escape()` when concatenating elements.

2)  Use a single, but complex, RegEx pattern and loose lists

```
  r"(When I ate at (?P<rest1>[^,]+), I felt (?P<feel1>[a-z]+).)|(I like eating at (?P<rest2>[^.]+)\.)"
```

This has the advantage that you can capture new restaurant names, feelings, etc.  The disadvantage is dependency on punctuation / grammar.  Example:  the first pattern would not recognize a restaurant name with an embedded `,` .

3)  Do what you are probably already doing.  Natural language analysis is much more complex than what RegEx's can do by themselves.

4)  If it's not just about a few fixed patterns, but about analyzing the meaning of a post regardless of specific wording, then you should use NLTK as other posters have suggested.